# iOS CoreMotion deviceMotion sensor polling vs callback

Tags: ios, multithreading, queue, latency, core-motion

My requirement: To have sensor updates affect sound generation with as low latency as possible.

With CMMotionManager, what would be the best solution for this - specifically should I use the motionManager callbacks, or polling?  With the callbacks, does anyone know if they get mixed up or are strictly FIFO + do they run serially or if a callback is blocked, do other ones still occur on different threads?

If I were to use polling, should I choose threads or which Queue should I run polled updates on (e.g. with an NSTimer based update every ms)?

Any other relevant experience with a similar requirement would be much appreciated in the comments.